# Why is the task from TaskCompletionSource not completed after 5 seconds?

Tags: c#, cancellationtokensource, taskcompletionsource

When I set the CancellationTokenSource to cancel after 5 seconds. The TaskCompletionSource will not be cancelled.

```
[Test]
public async Task Test()
{
  var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));      
  var completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource(cts.Token);

  await completionSource.Task;
}
```

Comment: May be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39897151/how-to-combine-taskcompletionsource-and-cancellationtokensource, mostly this part https://stackoverflow.com/a/39902447/2011071

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TaskCompletionSource` object doesn't take cancellation tokens in the constructor, it takes any `object`. It's not supposed to listen to cancellation tokens.

You can read the [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-threading-tasks-taskcompletionsource-ctor(system-object)) to see what the constructor does and how to use the `TaskCompletionSource` object.

You probably want to use the [`SetCanceled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource.setcanceled?view=net-6.0#system-threading-tasks-taskcompletionsource-setcanceled(system-threading-cancellationtoken)) method.